# Scipy odeint stopping

Tags: python, scipy

I was doing some simulation when I did observe an unexpected behavior in `scipy.integrate.odeint`.

I can reproduce my problem with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

tau = 0.01

a, b = 0.7, 0.8

def E_p(t):
    E = -0.07
    if t < b and t > a:
        E = -0.05
    return E

def dynamics(V, t):
    return (E_p(t) - V)/tau

time = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)
ps = odeint(dynamics, -0.07, time)

plt.plot(time, ps)
```

When I set a and b as an interval near the left ( the zero in my case ) `odeint` works well, instead with an interval to the right it doesn't nothing.

I expect to see this

[image: integration]

but more to the right. What I really want to do is simulate a square pulse in a RC circuit.

I believe that `odeint` stop integrating when it feels that the function has converged, but I can't find any documentation saying this.

Comment: I don't think `odeint` is able to cope with discontinuous functions like yours

Comment: Well, I did that image using a = 0.1 and b = 0.2, so it works in come cases. It would be nice to know when it works but I will assume that it doesn't work and use another function. In future I will also need to work with a general impulse response, so I need a function that handle discontinuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a discontinuity breaks the assumptions on which most ODE solvers are based, `odeint` often does a pretty good job handling one.  The problem here is likely caused by the adaptive step sizes used by the solver.  In cases like this, it is possible for the step size to be large enough that the solver skips right over the pulse--it never "sees" it.

Try using the `hmax` argument of `odeint`.  Set it to a value that is less than the width of the pulse.  That will ensure that `odeint` hits the pulse at least once.  Then the adaptive solver should resolve the bounds of the pulse reasonably well.  For example, this worked:

```
ps = odeint(dynamics, -0.07, time, hmax=0.2*(b-a))
```